# Android detect Bitmap too large

Tags: android, bitmap

I have the problem of Bitmap too large to...
I can resize the image with Picasso. The problem is that I have to detect WHEN I have to resize the image. How can I detect when the bitmap it’s going to be too large? How can I get the maximum value to compare if I need to resize or not?

I use :

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

I test this code in a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini and works.
I test this code in a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and not works.

Dont know what to do in the case of a note 3...

Comment: Did you enabled openGL in your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

In your android manifest add the `hardwareAccelerated` flag set to true, like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: If i add that the gl is going to return me the value?

Comment: I think that can be the problem, try it.