# image too large to be displayed

Tags: android, image

I am building an app to load images from the gallery, so far it's working well for some images, but some images i keep getting the message " Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2988x5312, max=4096x4096) "

here is the code to display the bitmap.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(filePath).error(R.drawable.smile).into(imageView1);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

what can i do to fix this ? resize the image ? or check to see if the image is too big ? and what is the resolution acceptable for images here ?

Comment: resize the image that will give take less memory and also it will not give you bitmapoutofmemory error in your project. If you rescale it with keeping aspect ratio then it will not looks blurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered yourself, yes you have to scale your image, with picasso that's easy, anyway check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896216/android-detect-bitmap-too-large/35896414#35896414) and the answer to check how to get the max texture size supported by a device.

Check [this link](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit) to know how to resample images with picasso.

Comment: In glad to know that !

Answer (score 2):

Picasso has good enough cache management features.
you can resize image,

```
Picasso
.with(context)
.load(YOUR IMAGE PATH)
.resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
.into(imageView);
```

or you can scale down image.

```
 Picasso
.with(context)
.load(YOUR IMAGE PATH])
.resize(1920, 1080) // your desire ratio
.onlyScaleDown() // the image will only be resized if it's bigger than 6000x2000 pixels.
.into(imageView);
```